# ar_pose no longer downloadable...new url?

Tags: ros, ar-pose, git

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm trying to clone the following git repository:

http://robotics.ccny.cuny.edu/git/ccny-ros-pkg/ccny_vision.git

But the cloning is failing.  Furthermore, when I try to access anything related tot he robotics.ccny.cuny.edu base url, I'm redirected through wayback machine (with no valid snapshots in June).  It seems like this repository is dead.  Does anyone know where the new one might be located, if there's one at all?  Is there any other way to get this package?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66909/ar_pose-no-longer-downloadable...new-url?/) by [aespielberg](https://answers.ros.org/users/147/aespielberg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2013-07-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It has moved to https://github.com/LucidOne/ar_tools

---

Originally posted by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) with karma: 4402 on 2013-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2